# how to select all week monday to sunday in mysql?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, pdo

I try to select dates to my query but I also want to get for example sunday even no sunday on the date of my sql. it gets sunday as zero.

here is mysql

```
SELECT
    DATE(log_date) DATE,
    COUNT(users) active_users,
    DATE_FORMAT(log_date,'%a') DAYNAME
FROM tbl_accounts
WHERE
    DATE(log_date) BETWEEN DATE(:now) - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND DATE(:now)
GROUP BY DATE(log_date);
```

What I what to happen is select monday to sunday even there is no sunday I still want to select moday and it will show zero value if empty? is it possible?

Sample Output: 
[image]

I want this output to become monday-sunday and then sunday will show zero if there is no sunday.

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: One option here would be to left join a calendar table to your current query.  This would include any date which appeared in the calendar table.

Comment: so I should have calendar table?

Comment: So this is simple what you need to do a select for each day of the week and insert them into a temp table and then query the temp table.

Comment: sample output provided

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean like this?

```
SELECT  t.DATE, IFNULL(t.active_users, 0) AS active_users, week.d 
FROM (
SELECT DATE(log_date) DATE,
    COUNT(users) active_users,
    DATE_FORMAT(log_date,'%a') DAYNAME
FROM tbl_accounts
WHERE DATE(log_date) BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY DATE(log_date)) AS t
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 'Sun' AS d
    UNION SELECT 'Mon' AS d
    UNION SELECT 'Tue' AS d
    UNION SELECT 'Wed' AS d
    UNION SELECT 'Thu' AS d
    UNION SELECT 'Fri' AS d
    UNION SELECT 'Sat' AS d
) AS week ON week.d = t.DAYNAME
```

The example result in MySQL look like picture below:

[image: Example in MySQL]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    DATE(log_date) DATE,
    COUNT(users) active_users,
    DATE_FORMAT(log_date,'%a') DAYNAME
FROM tbl_accounts
WHERE
    DATE(log_date) BETWEEN DATE(:now) - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND DATE(:now)and
DATENAME(dw , @date) <> 'Monday'
GROUP BY DATE(log_date);
```

Just exclude it by adding it in where clouse. `DATENAME(dw , @date) <> 'Monday'`
This is builtine functin MSSQL.